# How to pass variable with the json() response received from an api using JsonResponse in Django. TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: json, django, django-views, jsonresponse

This is my function in views.py which calls the api and send the response on html page.

```
   r = requests.post(RUN_URL, data=data)
   return JsonResponse(r.json(), safe=False)
```

I have a global variable 'counter' which I want to return along with that r.json().

```
   return JsonResponse(r.json(),counter, safe=False)
```

When I tried this code it gives me a error:

```
  TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: You can add it to the response, so `JsonResponse({'data': r.json(), 'counter': counter})`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary where you return both the data and the counter, like:

```
return JsonResponse({'data': r.json(), 'counter': counter})
```

> I have a global variable 'counter'.

Please do *not* use *global* variables. Global variables introduce a *global state*, which makes testing, refactoring, and distributing software very painful.

Comment: Hey I tried implementing this but then I couldn't get output on the html page. And I'll keep that in mind about the global variables. Thanks

Comment: @VirajGaonkar: if you make a request, and `data` is the response, you access the result with `data.data` and the counter with `data.counter`.

Comment: Is there any way where I can append the counter variable in the r.json() itself?

Comment: @VirajGaonkar: yes, but what is `r.json()`. If it is a list, it makes no sense to do this. Especially since sending lists as JSON data is *unsafe*: see https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/